# How change default channel on Spring Integration Flow with Java DSL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-integration

I do not understand very well, as I can change the error channel for all my integration flow. I need to handle exceptions like InvalidAccessTokenException that can be thrown in a subflow inside the router.

What I've tried is to handle exceptions from the default channel "errorChannel" by:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
   return IntegrationFlows.from("errorChannel")
       .handle("errorService", "handleError")
       .get();
}
```

This error is treated by a method with the following signature:

```
void handleError(Message<Exception> exception)
```

But the default behavior persists, that is to say it still shows the trace by console.

So my question is: in java DSL how can I configure an error channel? Is it possible to map a group of exceptions to a particular error channel to make the management service of that group more cohesive?.

The configuration of my integration flow I explain below:

```
@Configuration
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class InfrastructureConfiguration {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InfrastructureConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    private IFacebookService facebookService;

    @Autowired
    private IInstagramService instagramService;

    @Autowired
    private IYoutubeService youtubeService;

    /**
     * The Pollers builder factory can be used to configure common bean definitions or 
     * those created from IntegrationFlowBuilder EIP-methods
     */
    @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
    public PollerMetadata poller() {
        return Pollers.fixedDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).get();
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
        return executor;
    }

    /**
     * MongoDbMessageSource is an instance of MessageSource which returns a Message with a payload 
     * which is the result of execution of a Query
     */
    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public MessageSource<Object> mongoMessageSource(MongoDbFactory mongo) {
        MongoDbMessageSource messageSource = new MongoDbMessageSource(mongo, new LiteralExpression("{}"));
        messageSource.setExpectSingleResult(false);
        messageSource.setEntityClass(UserEntity.class);
        messageSource.setCollectionNameExpression(new LiteralExpression("users"));
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "storeChannel")
    public MessageHandler mongodbAdapter(MongoDbFactory mongo) throws Exception {
        MongoDbStoringMessageHandler adapter = new MongoDbStoringMessageHandler(mongo);
        adapter.setCollectionNameExpression(new LiteralExpression("comments"));
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("errorChannel")
                .handle("errorService", "handleError")
                .get();
    }


    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public IntegrationFlow processUsers(MongoDbFactory mongo, PollerMetadata poller) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(mongoMessageSource(mongo), c -> c.poller(poller))
                .<List<UserEntity>, Map<ObjectId, List<SocialMediaEntity>>>transform(userEntitiesList
                        -> userEntitiesList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(UserEntity::getId, UserEntity::getSocialMedia))
                )
                .split(new AbstractMessageSplitter() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object splitMessage(Message<?> msg) {
                        return ((Map<ObjectId, List<SocialMediaEntity>>) msg.getPayload()).entrySet();
                    }
                })
                .channel("directChannel_1")
                .enrichHeaders(s -> s.headerExpressions(h -> h.put("user-id", "payload.key")))
                .split(new AbstractMessageSplitter() {
                    @Override
                    protected Object splitMessage(Message<?> msg) {
                        return ((Entry<ObjectId, List<SocialMediaEntity>>) msg.getPayload()).getValue();
                    }
                })
                .channel(MessageChannels.executor("executorChannel", this.taskExecutor()))
                .<SocialMediaEntity, SocialMediaTypeEnum>route(p -> p.getType(),
                        m
                        -> m.subFlowMapping(SocialMediaTypeEnum.FACEBOOK, 
                                sf -> sf.handle(SocialMediaEntity.class, (p, h) -> facebookService.getComments(p.getAccessToken())))
                            .subFlowMapping(SocialMediaTypeEnum.YOUTUBE, 
                                sf -> sf.handle(SocialMediaEntity.class, (p, h) -> youtubeService.getComments(p.getAccessToken())))
                            .subFlowMapping(SocialMediaTypeEnum.INSTAGRAM, 
                                sf -> sf.handle(SocialMediaEntity.class, (p, h) -> instagramService.getComments(p.getAccessToken())))
                )
                .channel("directChannel_2")
                .aggregate()
                .channel("directChannel_3")
                .<List<List<CommentEntity>>, List<CommentEntity>>transform(comments -> 
                        comments.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .aggregate()
                .channel("directChannel_4")
                .<List<List<CommentEntity>>, List<CommentEntity>>transform(comments -> 
                        comments.stream().flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .channel("storeChannel")
                .get();
    }


    @PostConstruct
    protected void init(){
        Assert.notNull(facebookService, "The Facebook Service can not be null");
        Assert.notNull(instagramService, "The Instagram Service can not be null");
        Assert.notNull(youtubeService, "The Youtube Service can not be null");
    }

}
```

An example of an exception that can be launched in any of the social networking services is this:

```
public class InvalidAccessTokenException extends RuntimeException {

    private SocialMediaTypeEnum socialMediaType;
    private String accessToken;

    public InvalidAccessTokenException(SocialMediaTypeEnum socialMediaType, String accessToken) {
        this.socialMediaType = socialMediaType;
        this.accessToken = accessToken;
    }

    public SocialMediaTypeEnum getSocialMediaType() {
        return socialMediaType;
    }

    public String getAccessToken() {
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

Is it possible to bind this exception to a particular error channel?.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried changing the error channel using the PoolSpec as follows:

```
@Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
public PollerMetadata poller() {
    return Pollers.fixedDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .errorChannel("customErrorChannel")
         .get();
}
```

But messages still continue to go to the default channel 'errorChannel'.

Here is an excerpt of the log messages:

```
2017-07-25 20:20:51.922 DEBUG 3268 --- [ taskExecutor-4] o.s.i.channel.PublishSubscribeChannel    : preSend on channel 'errorChannel', message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is sanchez.sanchez.sergio.exception.InvalidAccessTokenException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=SocialMediaEntity{id=59778bf93681ac0cc4e20089, accessToken=maite_access_token_facebook, type=FACEBOOK, invalidToken=false}, headers={sequenceNumber=1, sequenceDetails=[[35dd7519-59cd-f0ea-69b2-c5fbb7c1c57f, 2, 5]], mongo_collectionName=users, sequenceSize=3, user-id=59778bf93681ac0cc4e20094, correlationId=6665f8ee-2bc9-e6c0-17de-35d63a0afaaa, id=6925b3ea-0b30-3304-b7f0-d235959d7db1, timestamp=1501006851466}], headers={id=6eb1789c-21d7-1814-48ee-77553abd99b9, timestamp=1501006851922}]
2017-07-25 20:20:51.923 DEBUG 3268 --- [ taskExecutor-5] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is sanchez.sanchez.sergio.exception.InvalidAccessTokenException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=SocialMediaEntity{id=59778bf93681ac0cc4e2008c, accessToken=david_access_token_facebook, type=FACEBOOK, invalidToken=false}, headers={sequenceNumber=1, sequenceDetails=[[35dd7519-59cd-f0ea-69b2-c5fbb7c1c57f, 4, 5]], mongo_collectionName=users, sequenceSize=3, user-id=59778bf93681ac0cc4e20095, correlationId=254f918f-52d2-1cff-7ba5-7343a39a8941, id=3a5989df-2af7-56d0-2697-5fcaf75a2891, timestamp=1501006851527}], headers={id=c270d1ef-68ac-cb6b-245f-11e567b5b7e8, timestamp=1501006851922}]
2017-07-25 20:20:51.922 DEBUG 3268 --- [ taskExecutor-3] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is sanchez.sanchez.sergio.exception.InvalidAccessTokenException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=SocialMediaEntity{id=59778bf93681ac0cc4e2008f, accessToken=elena_access_token_facebook, type=FACEBOOK, invalidToken=false}, headers={sequenceNumber=1, sequenceDetails=[[35dd7519-59cd-f0ea-69b2-c5fbb7c1c57f, 5, 5]], mongo_collectionName=users, sequenceSize=3, user-id=59778bf93681ac0cc4e20096, correlationId=1aba58bf-733e-f1ed-a82e-67f482ff3531, id=5eb9c517-f451-e2d6-938d-e436bb362aef, timestamp=1501006851549}], headers={id=30a965d3-f829-d6cf-c971-7b4ed2f15f88, timestamp=1501006851922}]
2017-07-25 20:20:51.923 DEBUG 3268 --- [ taskExecutor-4] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : _org.springframework.integration.errorLogger.handler received message: ErrorMessage [payload=org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is sanchez.sanchez.sergio.exception.InvalidAccessTokenException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=SocialMediaEntity{id=59778bf93681ac0cc4e20089, accessToken=maite_access_token_facebook, type=FACEBOOK, invalidToken=false}, headers={sequenceNumber=1, sequenceDetails=[[35dd7519-59cd-f0ea-69b2-c5fbb7c1c57f, 2, 5]], mongo_collectionName=users, sequenceSize=3, user-id=59778bf93681ac0cc4e20094, correlationId=6665f8ee-2bc9-e6c0-17de-35d63a0afaaa, id=6925b3ea-0b30-3304-b7f0-d235959d7db1, timestamp=1501006851466}], headers={id=6eb1789c-21d7-1814-48ee-77553abd99b9, timestamp=1501006851922}]
2017-07-25 20:20:51.927 ERROR 3268 --- [ taskExecutor-3] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is sanchez.sanchez.sergio.exception.InvalidAccessTokenException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=SocialMediaEntity{id=59778bf93681ac0cc4e2008f, accessToken=elena_access_token_facebook, type=FACEBOOK, invalidToken=false}, headers={sequenceNumber=1, sequenceDetails=[[35dd7519-59cd-f0ea-69b2-c5fbb7c1c57f, 5, 5]], mongo_collectionName=users, sequenceSize=3, user-id=59778bf93681ac0cc4e20096, correlationId=1aba58bf-733e-f1ed-a82e-67f482ff3531, id=5eb9c517-f451-e2d6-938d-e436bb362aef, timestamp=1501006851549}]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.LambdaMessageProcessor.processMessage(LambdaMessageProcessor.java:130)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.ServiceActivatingHandler.handleRequestMessage(ServiceActivatingHandler.java:89)
```

I have tried two new approaches to change the default error channel:

- Create a custom ErrorHandler with the error channel and declare it in the PoolSpec:

  @Bean
  public MessageChannel customErrorChannel() {
       return MessageChannels.direct("customErrorChannel").get();
  }

  @Bean
  public ErrorHandler errorHandler() {
     MessagePublishingErrorHandler messagePublishingErrorHandler = new MessagePublishingErrorHandler();
            messagePublishingErrorHandler.setDefaultErrorChannel(customErrorChannel());
    return messagePublishingErrorHandler;
  }

  @Bean(name = PollerMetadata.DEFAULT_POLLER)
  public PollerMetadata poller() {
     return Pollers.fixedDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .errorHandler(errorHandler())
            .get();
  }

**The error messages are still going to the default channel 'errorChannel'.**

- Adding the **MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL** header to explicitly indicate the error channel:

  .enrichHeaders(s -> 
                          s.headerExpressions(h -> h.put("user-id", "payload.key"))
                          .header(MessageHeaders.ERROR_CHANNEL, "customErrorChannel")
                  )

**If this approach works, error messages are directed to the "customErrorChannel".**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. There is an `ErrorMessageExceptionTypeRouter` for similar task. So, you will be able to route your `InvalidAccessTokenException` to the specific channel.

Also be aware that `PollerSpec` can be supplied with the `errorChannel()`, so you don't need to worry that all your exceptions go to the default `errorChannel`.

**UPDATE**

OK. After some your code investigation I see this:

```
.channel(MessageChannels.executor("executorChannel", this.taskExecutor()))
```

That means you shift your message to different thread and, therefore, any exception there is already far away from the `try...catch` of the poller's algorithm to send to your custom `customErrorChannel`.

The `ExecutorChannel` has this logic:

```
    if (!(this.executor instanceof ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor)) {
        ErrorHandler errorHandler = new MessagePublishingErrorHandler(
                new BeanFactoryChannelResolver(this.getBeanFactory()));
        this.executor = new ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor(this.executor, errorHandler);
    }
```

Where that `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` is really based on the `errorChannel` by default. What you can do here is something like declaration of similar bean for the `taskExecutor()` bean and injection your `customErrorChannel` into the `MessagePublishingErrorHandler`.

Another option which should work here with the `MessagePublishingErrorHandler` is `errorChannel` header population upstream the `executorChannel` definition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!. I changed the error channel using the PoolSpec with return Pollers.fixedDelay (10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).errorChannel ("customErrorChannel").get ();  But the error messages still go to the errorChannel

Comment: Reflect that change in your code in the question, please. I can't guess from the void.

Comment: Okay, I just added it.

Comment: Would you mind to share some logs on the matter? How can you confirm that messages go to the `errorChannel` instead of your `customErrorChannel` ?

Comment: Sorry, but the trace was the same as before. But I'll give you an extract above. Thank you!!

Comment: OK. Weird. Would you mind to "cook" some simple Spring Boot application to let me play from my side? Thanks

Comment: Ok, the project is here https://github.com/sergio11/spring-integration-sample. The project is simple.

Comment: `Field facebookCommentMapper in sanchez.sanchez.sergio.service.impl.FacebookServiceImpl required a bean of type 'sanchez.sanchez.sergio.mapper.IFacebookCommentMapper' that could not be found.`. That's not simple. I can't figure out from here what should I add else to make it work.

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer. Also pay attention here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler

Comment: Ok, Mappers from MapStructs library must be generated with the Maven goal generate-sources.